# Best way to use mod_rewrite to replace WordPress pages with static files

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

Here's the situation: I've got an old WordPress installation that I'd like to archive as static files, but I'd also like to preserve old URLs. I've already created the static archive with `wget` and sorted out the filenames and links. Now I'd like to configure Apache to intercept requests for the old dynamic URL and replace them with the new static one, e.g.:

```
http://www.example.org/log/?p=1234
```

or

```
http://www.example.org/log/index.php?p=1234
```

should redirect to

```
http://www.example.org/log/archives/1234.html
```

I've tried adding the following to the `VirtualHost` config for `example.org`, but to no effect -- I just get the PHP page.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /log/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} p=([^&;]*)
RewriteRule ^/$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/log/archives/%1.html [R,L]
```

I've enabled logging and I can see what look like other rules being applied, but not this one. None of my other guesses at match patterns for `%{REQUEST_URI}` seem to have any effect either (`log`, `log/`, `log.*`, even `.*`).

I'm new to `mod_rewrite` and this is mostly cargo cult, so I'm pretty sure I've gotten it wrong. Anyone know what I should be doing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Changing `RewriteRule ^/$` to `RewriteRule ^/log/*$`

As it is, your rule will never match anything because

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /log/`

States that the URL must contain `/log/` however

`RewriteRule ^/$...`

Will only match `/` exactly -- that is, the top level directory.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly right, and stupid of me. On a related note, do you know if there's a way I can strip the query string from the redirected URL?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure. I would have expected the query string to have been stripped given the `RewriteRule` you provided... sounds like you should post that as a new question :-)